# Spring Method Security causes Null values for autowired objects

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-aop

I've played a bit with spring securities method security and got a very strange behavior. I have several controller classes and the methods are annotated with @PreAuthorize to restrict access for certain user roles.

There is one Controller Class who's injected objects are null after adding method security. I debugged into my code and found the following:

[image]

*service* and *userService* are the injected objects

```
@Controller
public class OrderController {

    @Autowired
    private OrderService service;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
```

What seems strange to me is the value description of *this*: OrderController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1a7122f6. By removing all MethodSecurity annotations the class works as expected.

When I look at other Controller Classes which also use method security then they work just fine and the variable list in the debugger looks ok:

[image]

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService service;
```

I also searched for errors I could have made with the annotations but the annotations in OrderController look the same as in the other Controller classes. Here examples of the OrderController Class:

```
@Controller
public class OrderController {
              .
              .
              .
    @GetMapping("/dispo/dispo")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN') or hasAuthority('DISPATCH')")
    private String showDispoPage() {
        return "/dispo/dispo";
    }

    @GetMapping("/dispo/orderCreate")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN') or hasAuthority('AL_SYNC_ADMIN') or hasAuthority('CLIENT_USER') or hasAuthority('DISPATCH')")
    private String showCreateOrder(Model model) {
        List<MdUser> userList = service.getUsers();
        model.addAttribute("userList", userList);

        return "/dispo/orderCreate";
    }
}
```

And here an example of another Controller Class which workes as expected:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
                 .
                 .
                 .

    @GetMapping("/admin/user")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN') or hasAuthority('DISPATCH') or hasAuthority('WEBTOOL_USER')")
    public String showInvalidUserPage(Model model) {
        List<UserModel> invalidUserList = service.findInvalidUsers(service.getUsers());

        model.addAttribute("userList", invalidUserList);
        return "/admin/user";
    }

    @GetMapping("/admin/userCreate")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
    public String showNewUserPage(Model model) {
        UserModel user = new UserModel();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "/admin/userCreate";
    }
}
```

So what could possibly went wrong here? I don't understand why this one class has a different behavior than the other classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring Security uses AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) to "wrap" an annotated method with AOP advice. Once a method with a pre/post security annotation is invoked, the advice checks whether the user is authenticated and authorized. The method is invoked if it successfully verifies, otherwise some unauthorized/unauthenticed flow is traversed.

Spring AOP can only perform **runtime** weaving on **public** methods. The `showDispoPage` and `showCreateOrder` are both private, which might interfere with the security advice.

I would move the pre/post authorization annotations to the Service layer. Not only does it provide better separation between controller annotations and security annotations, it also safeguards against any future errors. For instance, in your current set up, any calls to the `UserService` method will not be verified if they are being invoked through a different Controller where the security annotations have been forgotten.

Furthermore, you may also choose to use `web security` (securing access to URIs, such as securing `/some/path`) along with the current `method level security` set up.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer.It solved my problem. I changed the methods in my OrderController class from private to public.
I will consider your advice to move the authorization annotations into the service layer. At the moment project lead insists on annotating the controller method but I will try to convince him with your description. Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

For Kotlin users, make sure the **method is not final**!

Two days wasted.

Comment: Thanks! Also wasted 2 days ;)